# Why does my click event only work once when generating HTML, but works correctly when console.logging?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom, events

It functions how I intend to in the console, and when generating HTML, but it only works once with HTML, whereas it always works with the console.  Do I need to use a loop here, and return the HTML that way?  I tried map, but its not an array.  Edit: Forgot the HTML, just added it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pokedex</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="main-header">Pokedex</h1>
<div id="main-container">

</div>
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
const container = document.getElementById('main-container');

function getPokemon(callback) {
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/';

xhr.onload = function() {
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
        const pokemon = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        container.innerHTML+=
        pokemon.results.map((poke, index)=>{ 
            return `
                <div class='cardFront'>
                    <img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${(index + 1).toString()}.png'></img>
                    <h4>${poke.name}</h4>
                </div>
            `
        }).join('');

        callback();
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.send();
}

function cardBack() {
const endPoint = this.lastChild.previousSibling.innerText;
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function() {
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
        const details = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 
        container.innerHTML+= `
            <div class='backSide'>
                <h4>${details.name}</h4>
                <h4>${details.types[0].type.name}</h4>
            </div>
        `
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + endPoint, true);
xhr.send();
}

getPokemon(()=>{
const cardFront = document.querySelectorAll('.cardFront');
cardFront.forEach((card)=> {
    card.addEventListener('click', cardBack);
})
});
```

Comment: Where's your html?

Comment: It's a dynamic button where you want to click?

Comment: @User1899289003 it's a pokemon card.  I already have the front side rendered, and then make an API call to a different endpoint, to fetch the data for the backside.  I'm just trying to get the backside to render at this point, when clicked with the correct information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the callback function for your click listener you're adding new html code to your main-container `<div>` element using it's **.innerHTML** property.
This will remove all existing event listeners - thus click will just fire once.

Though I would recommend creating a new `<div>` using

`var newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");`

and appending it to main-container by

`document.getElementById('main-container').appendChild(newDiv);`

the simpler solution in your case is replacing

```
container.innerHTML+= `
    <div class='backSide'>
        <h4>${details.name}</h4>
        <h4>${details.types[0].type.name}</h4>
    </div>
`
```

by

```
container.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", `
    <div class='backSide'>
        <h4>${details.name}</h4>
        <h4>${details.types[0].type.name}</h4>
    </div>
`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a version which seems to fit all the criteria. The request for the card back information is only made once the card is clicked and the card can be clicked again to return to the front. I'm doing this by building each card front and back inside the same div and toggling a "hidden" class between the two sides.

I would ordinarily use fetch() and promises, but kept your original code with xhr and callbacks.

CodePen is here: https://codepen.io/edlucas/pen/xxbepjM

**JS**

```
const container = document.getElementById('main-container');
const pokeNames = [];
let loading = false;

function getPokemon(callback) {

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/';

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            const pokemon = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            container.innerHTML +=
                pokemon.results.map((poke, index) => {
                    const pokeName = poke.name.replace(/\s/g, "");
                    pokeNames.push(poke.name);
                    return `
                                    <div id="poke-${pokeName}" class="poke-card">
                                    <div class='cardFront'>
                                            <img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${(index + 1).toString()}.png'></img>
                                            <h4>${pokeName}</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                            `
                }).join('');

            callback();
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();
}

function addCardBack(pokeName, callback) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            const details = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            const pokeContainer = document.getElementById(`poke-${pokeName}`);
            pokeContainer.innerHTML += `
                            <div class='cardBack'>
                                    <h4>${details.name}</h4>
                                    <h4>${details.types[0].type.name}</h4>
                            </div>
                    `;
            callback(pokeName);
        }
        loading = false;
    }
    loading = true;
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + pokeName, true);
    xhr.send();
}

function toggleCard(pokeName) {
    const cardBack = document.querySelectorAll(`#poke-${pokeName} .cardBack`)[0];

    if (!cardBack) {
        // Prevent a second click from calling this function again before data is loaded
        if (!loading) {
            addCardBack(pokeName, (pokeName) => {
                swapCards(pokeName);
            });
        }
    } else {
        swapCards(pokeName);
    }
}

function swapCards(pokeName) {
    const cardFront = document.querySelectorAll(`#poke-${pokeName} .cardFront`)[0];
    const cardBack = document.querySelectorAll(`#poke-${pokeName} .cardBack`)[0];

    if (cardFront.classList.contains('hidden')) {
        cardFront.classList.remove('hidden');
        cardBack.classList.add('hidden');
    } else {
        cardFront.classList.add('hidden');
        cardBack.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
}

getPokemon(() => {
    pokeNames.forEach((pokeName) => {
        const card = document.getElementById(`poke-${pokeName}`);
        card.addEventListener('click', () => toggleCard(pokeName));
    })
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.poke-card {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```